# IntelliJ IDEA not showing quick documentation in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I have a simple Dockerfile. When I edit it in IntelliJ IDEA and move my cursor to a docker command like

```
COPY
ADD
RUN
```

and then press F2, it doesn't show the quick documentation. I do have the Docker plugin installed.

[image]

F2/Quick Documentation works great in java source files.

Do you know if IDEA can show quick documentation for Dockerfiles? Do we need to import some DSL/grammar file in IntelliJ IDEA for this to work?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1 on Mac OS X High Sierra.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

use VSCode idea to show document
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5YEV.png)

Comment: This answer is unrelated to the question as it is asking about IntelliJ IDEA, not VS Code.